# why is my prompt displaying three times

Tags: assembly, x86, prompt, masm, irvine32

I am new to assembly and I am trying out simple code here,why is my prompt showing 3 times ? What do I need to do so it can only show me prompt once ?? I am missing a return somewhere ? I've tried ret for DisplayS and DisplayN and DisplayName but it still shows me twice...

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
;--------- Enter Data Here


        vS BYTE "************", 0
        vA BYTE "************", 0
        vName BYTE "*************", 0
        vHexPrompt BYTE "Please Enter the Value:" ,0
.code
main PROC
;--------- Enter Code Below Here

call Clrscr 
call DisplayS 
call DisplayA
call DisplayName 
call DisplayPrompt

call DisplayString
call EndProgram  
call Clrscr

;------------------------------------------------------------------

        DisplayS:
                mov dh, 4
                mov dl, 33
                call Gotoxy

                mov edx, OFFSET vS
                call WriteString

 ret
;------------------------------------------------------------------

        DisplayA:
                mov dh, 5
                mov dl, 33
                call Gotoxy

                mov edx, OFFSET vA
                call WriteString
 ret
;------------------------------------------------------------------

        DisplayName:
                mov dh, 6
                mov dl, 33
                call Gotoxy

                mov edx, OFFSET vName
                call WriteString
 ret
;------------------------------------------------------------------
        DisplayPrompt:
                mov dh, 8
                mov dl, 33
                call Gotoxy
                mov edx, OFFSET vHexPrompt
                call WriteString
ret
;------------------------------------------------------
DisplayString:
call WriteString
ret

;----------------------------------------------------------
EndProgram:
    xor ecx, ecx
    call ReadChar

    exit
main ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using `WriteString` to display a string.  `WriteString` uses `edx` to hold the address of the string to print.

You call `DisplayPrompt` and move the address of `vHexPrompt` into `edx`, then you call `DisplayString` and in that function, you call `WriteString`.  `edx` still contains the address of `vHexPrompt` which is why you are getting a double prompt.

Until you write more code to utilize `DisplayString`, either comment out the call to writestring in that function, or just add `xor  edx, edx` right before your call to `WriteString` in `DisplayString`